# Java tomcat how to queue only certain http Thread?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a stateless Java application deployed to a tomcat web server. Due to the nature of the data, at any given time, all http thread has to process for different key (in other words: all threads must be processing different key).

Hence,  i wrote a module that queue the http post if the key of the request is current in progress (by a http post before this). I will only continue to process the current http post once the previous http post with the same key has complete its process.

I have wrote a simple while loop with concurrenthashmap to test whether there is any previous request with the same key in progress. The performance is sub par and there is an unexpected behaviour. This is the code snippet:

```
//This part of code is place inside the servlet 
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> transQueue = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
private void inQueuePoll(String queueKey) {
   while(transQueue.containsKey(queueKey)){     
      synchronized(this){
         try{
            Thread.sleep(50); // i know this is bad, any idea to improve this?
            logger.trace("Wait for Que Key: "+queueKey + " );

            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    transQueue.put(queueKey, "");
}
```

At the end of each http post, at the finally block, i put: transQueue.remove(queueKey) to ensure i have remove it from the concurrenthashmap. However, in my worst nightmare, from the server log, i notice that before i remove the queueKey, another http post thread, manage to get out of the while loop above and continue the processing.

Is there anything i did wrong on the above code to "queue" the http thread?

Also any idea on how i can do this better is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, if I can restate your case for clarity. For any given key, all requests must process in a single thread; request for other keys, however, may process at the same time that the request for the first key is processing.

This strikes me as a fine fit for the [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). I would make your map a `<String, ExecutorService>` map, where the key is your queue key, and the value is a single-threaded executor (which can be obtained via [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)).

Given a key, you would obtain an `ExecutorService` from the map, and submit your [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to be processed. Because the `Executor` for this key is single-threaded, you can be assured that it will wait until the previous request(s) for that key have processed before this one is processed. A call to [get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) will then block until the processing for this request is done.